Room types drop drown diplay as blank
I am a beginner Laravel programmer. When I display the hotel details page, the room types dropdown is displayed as blank. I tested it using dd() and it shows as null. Below is the code I tried. What is the issue? Can someone help me solve it?
Hotel model
class Hotel extends Model
{ 
    protected $table = 'hotels';
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';
    protected $fillable = ['name', 'image', 'description', 'status'];

    public function rooms()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Room::class, 'hotel_id', 'id'); // Correctly references the rooms table
    }

    use HasFactory;
}

Room model
class Room extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'rooms';
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';
    protected $fillable = ['name', 'description', 'qty', 'hotel_id', 'status'];
    
    public function hotel()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Hotel::class, 'hotel_id', 'id'); // Assumes 'id' is the primary key of 'hotels'
    }
    
    public function images()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(RoomImage::class);
    }
    
    public function roomType()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(RoomType::class); // Ensure a room_type_id column exists
    }


    use HasFactory;
}

RoomType model
class RoomType extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'room_types';
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';
    protected $fillable = ['name', 'room_id', 'price'];
    
    public function room()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Room::class);
    }
    
    use HasFactory;
}

RoomImage Model
class RoomImage extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $table = 'room_images';
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';
    protected $fillable = ['room_id', 'image_path'];

    public function rooms()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Room::class);
    }
}

HomeController
public function showdetails($id)
{
    $hotel = Hotel::with([
        'rooms.images',       // Fetch related images for each room
        'rooms.roomType'      // Fetch related room type for each room
    ])->where('id', $id)->get();
   
    if ($hotel->isEmpty()) {
        abort(404, 'Hotel not found.');
    }
  
    return view('showdetails', ['hotel' => $hotel->first()]);
}

showdetails.blade.php
<h1>{{ $hotel->name }}</h1>
<p>{{ $hotel->description }}</p>

<h2>Rooms</h2>
<form action="{{ route('booking.bookRoom') }}" method="POST">
  @csrf
  <div>
    <label for="roomType">Select Room Type:</label>
    <select id="roomType" name="room_id" onchange="updatePrice()">
      <option value="">Select Type</option>
      @foreach($hotel->rooms as $room)
        @if ($room->roomTypes)
          @foreach($room->roomTypes as $roomType)
            <option value="{{ $roomType->id }}" data-price="{{ $roomType->price }}">
              {{ $roomType->name }} - ${{ $roomType->price }}
            </option>
          @endforeach
        @else
          <option value="" disabled>No Room Types Available</option>
        @endif
      @endforeach
    </select>
  </div>

  <div>
    <label for="quantity">Quantity:</label>
    <input type="number" id="quantity" name="quantity" value="1" min="1" onchange="calculateTotalPrice()">
  </div>

  <div>
    <p>Price per Room Type: $<span id="pricePerRoom">0.00</span></p>
    <p>Total Price: $<span id="totalPrice">0.00</span></p>
  </div>

  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Book Now</button>
</form>

<h3>Room Images</h3>
@foreach($hotel->rooms as $room)
  <h4>{{ $room->name }}</h4>
  <div>
    @foreach($room->images as $image)
      <img src="{{ asset('storage/' . $image->image_path) }}" alt="Room Image" width="100">
    @endforeach
  </div>
@endforeach



Whats a result for dd($hotel)?

where is the null you are talking about, the dd screenshot show 4 RoomType results for that room !! also this condition @if ($room->roomTypes) will always return true since an empty collection or a filled collection, in both case it's an instance of an object Collection so it returns true. change it to @if ($room->roomTypes->count()) it would work if it was the opposite relation, example $roomType->room since that either returns an instance of Room or null

Your function name for multiple room types in rooms model is "roomType"
and in view file, you are retrieving it using "roomTypes"
Also $room->roomType returns a collection in all cases (even with no results) since it's a hasMany relation. to check of there are results, you need to call count()
@if ($room->roomType->count())
    @foreach($room->roomType as $roomType)
        <option value="{{ $roomType->id }}" data-price="{{ $roomType->price }}">
            {{ $roomType->name }} - ${{ $roomType->price }}
        </option>
    @endforeach
@else
    <option value="" disabled>No Room Types Available</option>
@endif


i tried sir Undefined variable $room

can u add hotel model code here

i added above sir

add error screenshot if possible

i added aboxe screen

Call to undefined relationship [roomTypes] on model [App\Models\Room].

roomTypes doesn't exist, u have mentioned roomType in model file

how to do it sir

@mayukobi your issue is with @if ($room->roomTypes) change it to @if ($room->roomTypes->count())

@hetathakkar ;)
